# Code not working in Jupyter Notebook, csv file, name error

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, compiler-errors

The following code was working fine yesterday and now it only runs occasionally and gives the  'name not defined error for kameradata'. I am a novice and dont know if its jupyter or my code. I have tried restarting the kernel but it still isnt running as it did yesterday.

```
import csv

def read_file(file_name):
    data_list = []
    with open(file_name,'r', encoding = 'UTF-8') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader (f, delimiter = ';')
        return data_list

    for rad in csv_reader:
        data_list.append(rad)

read_file('kameraData.csv')
print(kameradata[0:3])
```

The csv file looks like this: `

```
MätplatsID;Gällande Hastighet;Hastighet;Datum;Tid
14075010;40;55;2021-09-11;11:15:31
14075010;40;54;2021-09-11;08:09:17
14075010;40;53;2021-09-11;13:02:41
14075010;40;49;2021-09-11;13:02:55
```

I want to use the function to print the first 3 rows as follows:

```
['MätplatsID', 'Gällande Hastighet', 'Hastighet', 'Datum', 'Tid'],  
   ['14075010', '40', '55', '2021-09-11', '11:15:31'], ['14075010', '40',  
    '54', '2021-09-11', '08:09:17']]
```

Comment: Well.. what is the variable `kameradata` supposed to be? It is not defined anywhere in the code you posted. Is it supposed to be the return value of `read_file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put return statement before loop and loop should be inside "with".
Try this code

```
def read_file(file_name):
    data_list = []
    with open(file_name,'r', encoding = 'UTF-8') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ';')
        for rad in csv_reader:
            data_list.append(rad)
        return data_list
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.